# Can I _.flatten based on multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore's flatten() and wondering if it's possible to compare multiple properties. I have array of objects with these properties:

```
{
    type: type
    startId: startId
    endId: endId
    dateCreated: dates.dateCreated
    dateEffectiveStart: dates.dateEffectiveStart
    dateEffectiveEnd: dates.dateEffectiveEnd
}
```

I want to compare the startId and the endId and if I see another object with the same start and end Id I want to ignore it.

Thank you!

Comment: [`flatten`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) is supposed to be used on arrays, not on objects. Can you please elaborate on what you [actually want to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Hey I guess me putting 'objects' wasn't clear enough. Sorry about that. Changed it to 'array of objects'. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rather combine `flatten` and `uniq`. This should do, what you ask for:

```
_.uniq(_.flatten(yourListOfObjects), function(o) {
   return o.startId + '<>' + o.endId;
});
```

If your ids happen to contain the string `'<>'` choose something else to concatenate the two ids.

Comment: Thanks Nikolas! I always used uniq() but didn't think of combining the two ids, duh!!